# Error creating Sql Server in Azure this location is not available for subscription

Tags: azure, sql

Im trying to create Sql Database resource and any location i select i get: 
"this location is not available for subscription"
Im trying to create WebAPP with Database. 
Plan is pay as you go

Answer (score 2):

It sounds that this is due to Covid-19 and the following statement:

https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/our-commitment-to-customers-and-microsoft-cloud-services-continuity/

*"As demand continues to grow, if we are faced with any capacity constraints in any region during this time, we have established clear criteria for the priority of new cloud capacity. Top priority will be going to first responders, health and emergency management services, critical government infrastructure organizational use, and ensuring remote workers stay up and running with the core functionality of Teams. We will also consider adjusting free offers, as necessary, to ensure support of existing customers."
You can use the Azure Portal to raise your request to access to a region. The access will be checked from case to case and access to locations given.*

So my advice is that you put in a support ticket to Microsoft.

Comment: No. I had this happen to me 1 year ago, so long before the current constraints. And now it's impossible to add new SQL Databases, the only region selection that doesn't return the OP's error is East US. I have an open SR with Azure support on this issue, will report back if there's a solution.